# Detecting data changes with Form events

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

If you've read my other recent questions, you've prob'ly picked up that I'm not *really* an Access developer.... Most of my background is in VB, where I assiduously avoided bound controls.

Now I'm working in Access 2007. I have form that's based on a table (well, a single-table query), and a subform upon it based on a one-to-many child table. I want to detect user-made changes in the data on either of these forms so that I can update a date stamp in the parent table. The actual date field is not being shown to the user (at least not here).

What would be the appropriate event to catch the fact that the change has been made? How should I make the actual change (direct to form.Recordset!dateField | with a hidden bound text box | some other way)?

Comment: You should consider maintaining your update stamp separately for the parent and child tables.

Comment: @David--I'm not carrying an update stamp on the child, but I want the parent update stamp updated when either the parent or child changes. The child is actually a many-to-many join table (the parent is a "kit" of "parts" (maintained separately), and my concern is over the composition of the kit (the child table in the original question), not over changes in the rows of the child _per se_).

Comment: I understand. I'm suggestiong you very likely may someday want to maintain the data on the last update to the child records separately from the update date for the parent record -- this is the voice of experience speaking. Also, I'm somewhat wary of storing data about child records in the parent record. I see it as a form of denormalization. With triggers, I wouldn't necessarily be so worried, but without them, I see it as problematic, since it's too easy for the data to get out of synch. A2010 provides the equivalent of triggers, BTW.

Comment: I don't really see it as "data about the child records", but as "data about the _collection_ of child records". I'll give your point some more thought, though. Boy do I wish I had triggers.... A2010 is not yet approved at this (mega-large) client.

Comment: The last update of the child records is a piece of data that can be derived from the update dates on the individual child records. However, I'd be much more concerned about not "polluting" the parent record with data about updates of fields other than what's in the parent record. I have been in too many situations where I needed to merge data from two databases and it was extremely helpful to have LASTUPDATED fields in all the tables. Your approach means there's no reliable data about when the parent record was last updated, since the child updates will overwrite it.

Comment: A hit--a very palpable hit.... I'll give it some more thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to look for the afterupdate event, which is fired when the updated content of a bound control is updated in the underlying recordset.

In this event procedure, you should be able to write the needed instruction to update your date field. It is not necessary to have it bound to any control on the form, as long as the field is in the recordset!

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. It's actually what I expected, but was unsure enough that it felt safer asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a trigger to update the stamp of the child table per line of item that the user have made changes.  I normally use it on afterupdate event in relation to the index number of the active line (if you are in a datasheet form or continues form) being edited.  But of course you can count on how many times each record was updated and you can update the stamp date of the last update.