# Finding Autonumber ID for new record in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

The question I asked [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403987/detecting-record-addition-and-obtaining-autonumber-id-for-new-record) was actually a two-part question. I accepted an answer that was perfect for the first part, but I'm still stumped on the second.

I've got a form tied to a table. The user (still just me, in develop mode, but still...), enters a new record in the form. How do I get the (Autonumber) ID of that record? Even after forcing a save, it doesn't seem to be anywhere I know how to find it.

The ID is not on the form anywhere, though it is in the underlying recordset. For that matter, the recordset seems to be pointing to the first record, not the newly-added one (I do know that this behavior is documented for pure-code DAO recordsets, but I'd expect the current record of form.recordset to be the one that's represented on the screen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the After Insert event:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
MsgBox Me.ID  ''Name of autonumber field
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to be the most straight-forward way to get the newly created Autonumber ID.

Comment: Accepted because it solved my problem--I didn't even need to use the event, though. I just didn't realize that the ID field would be a property of the form in that way. As I said somewhere back down the chain of related questions, I'm not really used to bound interface elements.

Comment: I should have said on your earlier question, it was obvious to me so I did not see that it is not that clear to someone new to Access.

Comment: No problem--we all see too many trees, not enough forest sometimes.

Comment: I don't understand how you can get the ID value if you don't have the field in the form's recordsource, as your question seems to say.

Comment: The OP clearly states `though it is in the underlying recordset`

Comment: Indeed--from my unbound background, it's not "on the form" if there isn't a control for it. I guess here in the bound world, it's "on the form" just by being in the recordsource. It's a learning experience....

Comment: OK, I got hung up on terminology. This is yet another one of those remedial Access questions that confuse me why they are coming up so often. I don't see how anybody could use Access for 20 minutes and not get that a field can be in the form's recordsource, yet not displayed on a form -- when you create a form with a recordsource, you have no controls on the form, yet, you have a list of fields to pick from to add to the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the .movelast command

> Set rstTemp etc
>   < rstTemp.addnew

populate fields

> rstTemp.update
>   rsttemp.movelast

The value of `rstTemp!ID` where ID is the autonumber field will be the autonumber value